# javascript cookies on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hey can someone help me with cookies for a school assignment. The game I made is a murder mystery and I have to find objects. When I click the objects I want them to be saved to cookies and be able to get the images on a different page but only once they are clicked. Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better than cookies might be this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Here's how to decide:

[Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)